# How to ENABLE close button in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Why when I run code bellow, I don't have close button, like on this screenshot?

[image]

There is also no close button with other flags, like `Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint` or `Qt::WindowMinMaxButtonsHint` and other.

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget wgt;
    wgt.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint);
    wgt.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Close button is available with  `wgt.setWindowFlag(Qt::Window)`. Even without `wgt.setWindowFlag()` is still available. But as soon as I add second flag like `Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint` or any other, with button, that must become unavailable, close button become unclickable too.

Comment: Change `wgt.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint);` to `wgt.setWindowFlags(wgt.windowFlags() | Qt::Window);`

Comment: Did you compare your program to the Qt "Hello world"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget wgt;
    wgt.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
    wgt.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

More info:

A window flag is either a type or a hint. A type is used to specify various window-system properties for the widget.

[Window Flags Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html)

Comment: I mean that it is ok without flags(Ordinary window without any unclickable buttons). Close button disappears when I add any of second flag.

Comment: @Kamerton can you explain more ? maybe updating your question.

Comment: I found out, that everything I should do is to add `Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint` flag.

Comment: @Kamerton glad to help